# Won't Pass Object

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been working on asteroids but my random moving *asteroid* function won't happen. Here is the code-

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.shape = canvas.create_rectangle(910, 540, 960, 590, outline = "blue", fill= "white")
        self.pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.yspeed = 0

    def move(self, canvas):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        self.pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)


class Asteroid():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.One = canvas.create_oval(0,0, 50, 50, fill="grey")
        self.speedx = (10)
        self.speedy = (10)

    def move(self, canvas):
        while True:
            self.canvas.move(self.One, self.speedx, self.speedy)
            self.canvas.after(20)
            self.canvas.update()


def game():
    #create window and canvas
    parent = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(parent, width = 1920, height = 1080, 
    background="black")
    parent.title("Asteroids")
    canvas.pack()

    #create player
    player = Player(canvas)
    enemyOne = Asteroid(canvas)
    enemyOne.move(canvas)
```

And I get the error message-

```
AttributeError: 'Asteroid' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

So the object canvas isn't being passed to Asteroids and def move. I included class Player for reference to show that passing canvas worked in the past. Thanks.

Comment: It's not an attribute, but it **is** being passed. You could assign it as an attribute in `__init__` (`self.canvas = canvas`) then you wouldn't *need* to pass it into `move`. Or, if you don't want it to be an attribute, explicitly pass it and *don't* access it via `self`. But the current mix and match doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor call to `Asteriod()` passes in `canvas` as a parameter. But the constructor doesn't create an attribute called `canvas`, in other words there is no assignment

```
self.canvas = canvas
```

But the method `move()` calls `self.canvas.move()` which implies that `self.canvas` must exist. It doesn't, and that is why you get the message `'Asteroid' object has no attribute 'canvas'`.